# Elapsed time in x axis - chart control

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am very new to C++/cli. I need to plot some real time data in chart control (voltage vs time). My x axis should show elapsed time. Like 1,10, 20, 30... sec with an interval of  10sec. After plotting 50 points I am removing the 1st point. (RemoveAt(0)). So I don't want to keep my 1 sec label in plot. it should be role over as the time increases. ie, after 50 sec, my x axis should show 50, 60, 70...not 1,10,20,30...My x axis is showing upto 50 and it is not showing any further labels since I am removing the points from index 0. Plotting is keep on going,but labels are not displaying properly. How to keep the x axis label? (eg: 10, 20, 30...depends on time). How to resolve this? somebody please help me.
In short how to do X axis shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this issue is we need to manually force the chart to do a recalculation 
 using ResetAutoValues(); 
usage  :   chart1->ResetAutoValues();